# Will this 18650 tp4056 parallel circuit work for charging and simultaneous power supply or will things break?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, parallel, charge

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9sl5D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hey guys it's my first post here and i'm a bit unsure with this circuit, will it work or will there be some problems?

My suspicion is that the charging won't work correctly and there could be some under or over charging / balance issues but I'm not sure.

Also the current draw from the transformers will range from 500 mili amp to 4A depending on peripherals attached so on dead batteries im unsure if the transformers will get enough power as two tp4056's can only provide 2A, maybe a way of fixing it would be to add extra wires going from the tp4056 'in' pins to the 'in' pins of the transformers? (provided the micro usb 'in' supplies atleast 6A i would presume it could power the device while still charging the batteries?)

**______________________________**

[YH11062B boost converter data sheet](http://www.droking.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/090485.pdf)

- Input voltage: 2.6-5.5V
  Input Current: 0-3A
  Output voltage: 5V
  Output current: 0-2A
  Short circuit protection: Yes

TP4056 DATASHEET: https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf

Help would be much appreciated!

(EDIT: Datasheet + Circuit Diagram, hope this one is better //*i'm new to circuit schematics*)

Comment: Instead of posting a messy diagram how about making it not messy?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There is a built-in schematic tool with a button on the editor toolbar. There are battery symbols, switches, etc., and a generic multi-pin component that will enable you to draw a meaningful schematic. You should also post links to datasheets for any devices used.

Comment: No, it will not work. They will fight each other.

Comment: Why? And how can i fix it?

Comment: The TP4056 is designed for one thing and one thing only - charging a battery. It's not designed to power other things at the same time as it will have no idea what current is going into the battery and what is going elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your new and improved schematic shows that you have parallel connected the batteries and charger outputs. There is no way for each charger to know which battery is being charged.

[image]

*Figure 1. The only circuit given in the TP4056 datasheet.*

With only one example application that datasheet doesn't give a lot of help. I'd look around for a similar chip with more sample applications.

Comment: Thanks, I will do just that. Just to clarify one thing, if i were to remove the 2nd tp4056 and battery would my circuit function correctly?

Comment: If you configure as per the datasheet I don't see why not. I don't know about the YH devices.

Comment: Say for example the battery is charged but i still supply power to the tp4056, won't the tp4056 supply power to the rest of the circuit but also overcharge the battery?

Comment: I can't answer this at the moment. I suggest you read up on battery management solutions and application notes. There must be thousands of articles on this as most USB powered devices can run while the batteries are charged.

Comment: I found this - http://www.ebay.com/itm/2S-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-3-7v-18650-Charger-BMS-Protection-Board-5A-7-4V-8-4V-/322372551419 would it do the trick and charge the batteries and also allow current for the rest of the circuit if i use a 2S setup and supply 8.4v? (Using buck converter instead) Sorry i couldn't find the datasheet for it

Comment: No datasheet - no sale.

Comment: In theory if i did do that and supplied 8.4v to the BMS, but connected a 6v minimum->5v buck converter in aswell from the BMS,  would that mean the BMS would only get 2.4v to charge the the batteries?

Comment: Or would it just be the potential current that drops so it would charge slower?